# Sample divided in three equal categories of individuals in logit regression

Tags: logistic, sample, logit

I am analysing a dataset composed by three groups of individuals: unemployed, unstable workers and regular workers. These three groups are numerically equal (400 individuals in each category). I am running a logit analysis to test the effect of occupational status (regular worker, unemployed and unstable worker) on a bivariate dependent variable (dummy 0 or 1). I use as regressors (independent variables) a categorical variables 1-3 to indicate occupational status and others regressors (educational level, gender etc.etc.).
Is it correct to use occupational status as a regressor even if my dataset is not a random sample, but is built "artificially" to have three equal groups of individuals? I have terrible doubts on the procedure! If anybody have suggestions I would be glad.
Thanks,Lara

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's OK as long as the 400 individuals in each category were randomly selected from all the members of the category.  If they were, you have a stratified, but nonetheless random, sample.

Where things may go a little wrong is if there's some model misspecification, for example, the slope of some regressor actually varies across occupational status but the model forces it to be the same across occupational status.  If the dataset were not stratified, one could still interpret the slope as a weighted average of the three underlying slopes, with weights more-or-less proportional to the fraction of the population with each occupational status (there are other influences on the weights too,) but with the current scheme, the slopes won't have this nice "average slope across the population" interpretation.  Still, you'd rather not misspecify the model more than necessary.

Comment: Randomness is good, but is it really necessary?  This situation appears to be akin to a scientific experiment in which the investigator *purposely* sets the dial of a black box to a determined value (analogous to employment status) and observes an outcome (the dependent variable).  All we really need is that the *residuals* in the regression be independent of the selection of the individuals.  Thus, even if this dataset were not created by randomization, it still could be rescued.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll need to run logit diagnostics to check the goodness of fit of my model. And I still need to go more in depth in that "mispecification" matter.